# FTP text editor - Mac

Tags: macos, ftp, text-editors

Perhaps this isn't the proper thing to ask the Stack Overflow community, but I can't think of a better place to ask.

Can anyone suggest a free text editor for the Mac that allows for FTP

I currently use Text Wrangler, and recently started using Coda (which I love), but my free trial is ending on Coda. Anyone have good ones?

Comment: What's wrong with sticking with TextWrangler ?

Comment: You can use `lftp` with the EDITOR variable set properly.

Comment: I've never understood: why do you want FTP in your text editor? There are programs (and command line utilities) that do FTP well already. Choose a text editor for its text-editing features; FTP separately.

Comment: I'm not overly happy with TextWrangler's interface. And I don't FTP separately because I'm not an expert at command line FTP utilities, and it is much nicer to use interface sides.

Comment: emacs, unsurprisingly, has FTP support built-in.

Comment: Phrogz: Same reason I've wanted every other feature that my text editor has: because it's convenient.  There are perfectly good external tools to do "search in document", too, but I see nothing to be gained by needing to add more programs and more steps to use them.

Comment: Kod http://kodapp.com/ will have it eventually, try removing any trace of Coda to get another trial?

Answer (score 1):

Use a GUI FTP client such as Cyberduck or Transmit.

Editors and FTP clients on Mac OS X are usually well integrated, allowing you to edit files "directly on the server" when initiating the edit in your editor from the FTP client.